# Python error "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" but file is there

Tags: python, file, io

I am trying to read a csv file and I am getting the error above but the file is there.    The line giving the error is

```
infilequery = file('D:\x88_2.csv','rb')
```

and I get the error below.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\usrapply_onemol2.py", line 14, in 
    infilequery = file('D:\x88_2.csv','rb') 
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\x88_2.csv'

I can put a file from the same directory in its place and python at least sees it.  The result of os.listdir("D:") features 'x88_2.csv' and the result of "dir D:\" also includes it.  When putting the filename in and allowing python to complete the path and selecting x88_2.csv from the dropdown, I still get the same error.  What is up here?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
'D:\\x88_2.csv'
```

The `\x88` is interpreted as the character at code point 0x88. Alternatively you could use raw string

```
r'D:\x88_2.csv'
```

or forward slash

```
'D:/x88_2.csv'
```